# Get element by class - with dashes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg

I am trying to access some svg elements on a page given their class name. However, it does not work, when the class name contains dashes. Is there some work around?

```
<svg width="100" height="20" class="123-456">
    <rect width="50" height="20" style="fill:red" />
</svg>
<svg width="100" height="20" class="567-345">
    <rect width="50" height="20" style="fill:red" />
</svg>
<svg width="100" height="20" class="123-456">
    <rect width="50" height="20" style="fill:red" />
</svg>

<br>
    <a href="#" onclick="highlightSVG(123-456)">highlight</a>
```

JS:

```
function highlightSVG(conversationid) {
    $('[class="' + conversationid + '"]').css('width','20');
}
```

Here is a link to fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/93FHf/

It works if I remove the dashes but in that case, I would have to change some naming conventions in my project :-/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works if the value passed in for the function is quoted!

```
onclick="highlightSVG('123-456')"
```

You can also simply use the class selector rather than an attribute selector:

```
$("." + conversationid)...
```

Comment: Oh, pfft, I was halfway through testing before I noticed this. As it is right now it's looking for an element with `class="-333"`

Comment: Ah, that did not hit me xD Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

you are passing in argument 123-456.
When it is retrieved in Javascript it perform arithmetic operation and this result as -333.

you pass it as a string in argument than it will work for you.

Follow updated fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
   <a href="#" onclick="highlightSVG(123-456)">highlight</a>
```

To

```
   <a href="#" onclick="highlightSVG('123-456')">highlight</a>
```

And

```
$('[class="' + conversationid + '"]').css('width','20');
```

To

```
$('.'+conversationid).css('width','20');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <a href="#" data-myclass ='123-456' onclick="highlightSVG(this)">highlight</a>


function highlightSVG(conversationid) {
var colClass = $(el).data('myclass ');
}
```

try with custom data. bcz directly it will not take selector dashes